# Visual Studio Associated Automation not showing tests when attempting to link to MTM

Tags: visual-studio-2012, testing, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

When attempting to link up a test in Visual Studio to Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) via the "Associated Automation" tab, the tests created in visual studio aren't showing up.

This is an issue with a number of projects in the solution. I have tried re-building the solution but they still do not display. Some show, some don't. What could be the issue with this occurring and how can this be remedied?

Comment: Make sure the solutin the tests belong to is open in Visual Studio if you are trying to setup "Associated Automation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was being that if the projects were not created as a variation of any of the "Test" projects in Visual Studio, the tests won't show up on the associated automation test names when linking to the MTM test case.